# How to flash stm32 using only Linux terminal?

Tags: c++, linux, stm32

So, threre are Archlinux distro, stm32 mc, and C code. How to flash stm32, without some IDE, only using console?

Comment: Can you please brief?

Comment: This is generally question. Is it real to do this? And how usualy people do it.

Comment: It is possible, but you haven't given us enough details for a useful answer.

Comment: What details? All stm32 controllers are flashed the same way. OK, there are actually two ways, if one fails, try the other.

Answer (score 13):

**With [Texane stlink](https://github.com/texane/stlink)**

1. Install as described in the [README](https://github.com/texane/stlink/blob/master/README)
2. Convert your firmware to `.bin` if necessary
   `arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary firmware.elf firmware.bin`
3. `/opt/stlink/st-flash write firmware.bin 0x8000000`

**With [OpenOCD](https://github.com/gnuarmeclipse/openocd/releases)**, if your board is not supported by Texane

1. Get it from the link above and [install](http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/openocd/install/#gnulinux) (ignore the eclipse-specific parts)
2. Find your board description file in `openocd/scripts/board`, create one if necessary.
3. `openocd -d0 -f board/yourboard.cfg -c "init;targets;halt;flash write_image erase firmware.hex;shutdown"`

Answer (score 5):

If you have USB to UART adapter, you can use [`stm32flash`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/stm32flash/). Basically connect `USART1` to the adapter, pull `BOOT0` to high (there might be a jumper or button on the board) and power up / reset the board. Then you should be able to follow `stm32flash -h` to see what to do.

Some STM32 (e.g. `STM32F042`) has USB DFU bootloader built in, so you can also connect the MCU to USB directly and use [`dfu-utils`](http://dfu-util.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: An example Makefile can be found [here](https://github.com/dword1511/stm32-vserprog/blob/master/Makefile#L114)